# dynamic pl/sql invocation returning non SQL type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, boolean

I'm trying to dynamically invoke a PL/SQL method that returns a boolean with no luck. I've looked all around for an answer, but it seems like this is impossible.

Here is a very simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```
create or replace 
function test_ret_bool return boolean as 
begin
  return true;
end test_ret_bool;
```

and then the invocation:

```
declare
  ret_val boolean;
  sql_stmt varchar2(1000);
begin  
  sql_stmt := 'select test_ret_bool() from dual';
  execute immediate sql_stmt into ret_val;
end;
```

This doesn't work, generating the error:

```
ORA-06553: PLS-382: expression is of wrong type
```

Also I tried changing sql_stmt to:

```
sql_stmt := 'begin :result := test_ret_bool(); end;';
execute immediate sql_stmt using out ret_val;
```

to invoke then PL/SQL engine, but that gives this error:

```
PLS-00457: expressions have to be of SQL types
```

I've seen other threads describing the same issue and perhaps using wrapper functions. It's not possible for me to use a wrapper function in my situation.

I've seen some ideas around using dbms_sql.execute() for this possibly, but haven't gotten it to work.

Can anyone please advise? Can some provide an example of this working using dbms_sql.execute()?

Thanks much!

Comment: Why can't you use a wrapper? this works- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2a00/4

Comment: Which version of oracle?

Comment: @A.B.Cade That's a working solution, please post it.

Comment: Version is: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: I can't use a wrapper. I'm using the template method design pattern. A good PL/SQL example is here: http://technology.amis.nl/2006/03/10/design-patterns-in-plsql-the-template-pattern/  I need to take in the pkg_name and then use the name to call to methods in the passed in package.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you need to call a function returning a BOOLEAN in SQL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bool support Oracle SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491508/bool-support-oracle-sql)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Oracle functions `SYS.DIUTIL.bool_to_int` and `SYS.DIUTIL.int_to_bool`.

Comment: This is just a variant on the already proposed wrapper, which the OP reckons they can't use.

Comment: Nevertheless, it should be mentioned that one should not write such wrappers because they are already exist in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is fine, the issue is that Oracle doesn't support the `boolean` datatype in SQL. If you want to you this you've either got to use pure PL/SQL (as in A.B.Cade's SQLfiddle), or convert the boolean into Y/N, 1/0 or similar.

You can see the supported datatypes [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF0021).

Comment: Notice that in Oracle SQL & PL/SQL are different languages, supporting different types. PL/SQL supporting boolean while SQL does not is one example. PL/SQL has a max VARCHAR2 size of 32767, while SQL's max size is 4000. Other differences exist.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, but I was hoping I could achieve this by using the PL/SQL engine or something, or dbms_sql.execute(). My code gets littered with if '1' then return true, else return false...because the rest of the code base is expecting booleans. So I'm trying to avoid this mess.

Answer (score -2):

This is equiv. of what trying to do:

```
SELECT * FROM dual WHERE 1=1; -- TRUE

SELECT * FROM dual WHERE 1=2; -- FALSE
```

Comment: The OP wants to return a boolean in SQL.  Those queries return *something* and *an empty set* respectively, which is not relevant.

Comment: @@APC - Maybe the OP will find this useful as it is clear to me that OP is a beginner and looking for all possible info and examples. And I still do not know what OP means :)