# How to implicitly convert one class to another in Scala

Tags: oracle, scala, mapping

I'm writing a simple class, `BooleanChar`, to wrap a boolean in a `Char` for Oracle (because [Oracle is stupid or, TL;DR Oracle SQL does not support booleans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491508/bool-support-oracle-sql)).

So, I have model classes (that will use the `BooleanChar`). I also have projection classes, or objects that map to REST, etc., that will use `Boolean`.

Example (contrived and simple but to the point):

```
val first: String = "Fred"
val last: String = "Flintstone"
val active: BooleanChar = BooleanChar(true)

val m = UserModel(first, last, active)
... // stuff happens and now I want to project it over REST
val u = User(m.first, m.last, m.active)
```

Now, the trick is, I'd like the mapping of `m.active` (either a `BooleanChar` on the model, or a `Boolean` on the projection) to be totally transparent. Hence if these two classes were interchangeable, the above works very nicely, even if:

```
case class User(first: String, last: String, active: Boolean)
```

But this all hinges on a magical mapping between the two types of objects, such that `a: BooleanChar = b: Boolean` in some way. Otherwise, I have to do this all over the place, and it's ugly:

```
val u = User(first, last, active.map(_.state)) // BooleanChar has a `Boolean` `state`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Pimp My Library pattern](https://coderwall.com/p/k_1jzw/scala-s-pimp-my-library-pattern-example):

Basically what you want is something like

```
class BooleanCharToBool(bc: BooleanChar) {
    def toBool = bc.map(_.state)
}

implicit def booleanCharToBool(bc: BooleanChar) = new BooleanCharToBool(bc)
```

Once you import this to the scope in which you want to do the conversion (where you construct a `User`), the compiler will notice that there is a way to implicitly convert a BooleanChar to a Boolean, and you will be able to do

```
val u = User(first, last, active)
```